# Getting dictionary with all resources and pseudo-random picking value based on key

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, resources

Lets assume I have multiple sprites in quite elaborate directory tree in my `Assests/Resources` folder. I would like to load all sprites from `Assests/Resources/gfx` (if fact - from all its subfolders; `gfx` self has no sprites) and store them in `Dictionary<string, Sprite> sprites;` .
Here is my code:

```
void LoadSprites() {
        buildingSprites = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();
        Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("gfx/");

        Debug.Log("Loaded following resources:");
        foreach(Sprite s in sprites) {
            //Debug.Log(s);
            string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (s);
            path = path.Remove (0, 17); // "assets/resources" bit
            Debug.Log ("Found asset " + s + " in path: " + path);
            buildingSprites[s.path] = s;
        }
    }
}
```

Thing is that if I ever ask for given path, I would like to get a random sprite that matches the path. For example if I had folder `ABC` somewhere in `Assests/Resources/gfx` with sprites `X`,`Y` and `Z`, then I want to get only one of these spites via function providing path to `ABC` (so I can assign it to my Gameobject or whatever).

**My questions:**

1. How to get sprite's asset `path`?
2. How to store full `path + name` as a dictionary key? (Should be obvious when 1. is answered, but I want to point out that presumably this will be only usage of getting the `path`)
3. How to get any value from dictionary by providing only `path` part of
   the key and looking for anything that matches?
4. How to get random value from dictionary by providing only `path` part
   of the key and looking for everything that matches?

Comment: Do you really *need* the string? If you are only retrieving one at random, then all you need is an array or list and retrieving based on a random index in that array.

Comment: It's not about complete random retrival. It should be random only within every directory.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do this automatically. Resources.LoadAll just returns the objects, but those objects don't know about their own path (they're like any other object of their Type)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you could not store the data like that anyway, you would need to store a list of sprites for each directory level you are in.. Since i have a lot of free time i did this..

Considerations:

- If a directory is empty(or only contains folders), it won't have any entries in the dictionary, and it wont have a key in the dictionary.You can figure out this part ;)
- note that I store a List> instead of a sprite per path.
- Remember the includes when creating the class
- Actually read the code please, there's a lot to learn here.
  code:

`

```
Dictionary<string, List<Sprite>> buildingSprites;

void Start()
{
    LoadSprites();
}

void LoadSprites() {
    buildingSprites = new Dictionary<string, List<Sprite>>();
    Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("gfx/");
    foreach (Sprite s in sprites) {
        string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(s);
        path = path.Remove(0, 17);
        addToDictionary(path, s);
    }

    string FOLDER_NAME = "/"; // FODLER NAME SHOULD BE LIKE /ABC/ ... OR / FOR ROOT DIRECTORY
    if (!buildingSprites.ContainsKey(FOLDER_NAME)) {
        Debug.LogWarning("Wheres the folder: " + FOLDER_NAME + "?");
        return;
    }

    foreach (Sprite s in getEntriesThatStartWith(FOLDER_NAME, false))
        Debug.Log(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(s));

    // GET A RANDOM SPRITE ?

    Sprite aRandomSprite =   (getRandomSprite ( getEntriesThatStartWith (FOLDER_NAME , true)));

}

Sprite getRandomSprite(List<Sprite> sprites){
    int randomIndex = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(0f, 1f) * sprites.Count );
    return sprites[randomIndex];
}

List<Sprite> getEntriesThatStartWith(string prefix, bool allowSubFolders){
    if (!allowSubFolders && buildingSprites.ContainsKey(prefix)) {
        return buildingSprites[prefix];
    }
    else if (allowSubFolders) {
        List<Sprite> allSubSprites = new List<Sprite>();
        foreach (string s in buildingSprites.Keys)
            if (s.StartsWith(prefix))
                foreach (Sprite subSprite in buildingSprites[s])
                    allSubSprites.Add(subSprite);
        return allSubSprites;
    }

    return null;
}

void addToDictionary (string path_with_name , Sprite spriteToAdd ) {
    string path = getPath (path_with_name);
    List<Sprite> sprites = null;
    buildingSprites.TryGetValue (path , out sprites );

    if (sprites == null){
        sprites = new List<Sprite>();
        buildingSprites.Add(path, sprites);
    }
    sprites.Add(spriteToAdd);
}

string getPath (string path_with_name) {
    int firstIndex = path_with_name.IndexOf('/');
    int lastIndex = path_with_name.LastIndexOf('/');
    return path_with_name.Substring(firstIndex, lastIndex - firstIndex + 1);
}
```

`